# Android edittext gets wrong keyboardtype in viewpager

Tags: c#, android, android-edittext, xamarin, android-viewpager

I've got this app with multiple fragments in a viewpager. These fragments all show an EditText, most of them having inputtype numberDecimal, three of them having no inputtype specified. 
Outside this viewpager there is another edittext which serves as searchbox.

I've done some manual focusing inside the touch event of the EditText to gain the right EditText focus inside the viewpager. (because of an issue similar to the one described here: [ViewPager focus issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161261/viewpager-focus-issue))

When I select the first EditText in my ViewPager, the right keyboard type shows up (nummeric). Now when I choose the next EditText the default keyboard shows up while having specified inpytType numberDecimal. 
When I remove the (search) EditText outside the viewPager and repeat the above scenario, the second EditText does get the correct keyboardtype. 
To me it almost looks like the search EditText is stealing focus somehow from the EditText inside my Fragment that's inside the viewpager.

How can I prevent it from doing this?

I already gave it's parent the android:focusableInTouchMode="true" property.

My MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "viewpagertest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    private CustomViewPager _viewPager;
    private CustomViewPagerAdapter _adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        _viewPager = FindViewById<CustomViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
        _adapter = new CustomViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        _viewPager.Adapter = _adapter;
        _viewPager.PageSelected += _viewPager_PageSelected;

    }

    void _viewPager_PageSelected(object sender, Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewPager.UnfocusFocusedView();
    }

    public void EditTextFieldClicked(View parentView, EditText editText)
    {
        _viewPager.RequestManualChildFocus(parentView, editText);
    }

    private class CustomViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly List<Fragment> _fragments;

        private int FragmentsPerPage { get { return 5; } }
        public CustomViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
            : base(fm)
        {
            _fragments = new List<Fragment>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (i == 3 || i == 9 || i == 15)
                {
                    _fragments.Add(new FragmentTestString());
                }
                else
                {
                    _fragments.Add(new FragmentTest());
                }
            }
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return _fragments[position];
        }

        public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object @object)
        {
            return PositionNone;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return 20; }
        }

        public override float GetPageWidth(int position)
        {
            return 1.0f / FragmentsPerPage;
        }
    }
}
```

My MainActivity xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtSearch"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<viewpagertest.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My custom viewpager to be able to focus manually

```
class CustomViewPager : ViewPager
{
    private View _prevFocusedView;
    protected CustomViewPager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public override void RequestChildFocus(View child, View focused)
    {
        //Do nothing, disables automatic focus behaviour
    }

    public void RequestManualChildFocus(View child, View focused)
    {
        if (_prevFocusedView != focused)
        {
            if (_prevFocusedView != null)
            {
                _prevFocusedView.ClearFocus();
            }

            base.RequestChildFocus(child, focused);

            _prevFocusedView = focused;
        }
    }

    public void UnfocusFocusedView()
    {
        var etxt = _prevFocusedView as EditText;
        if (etxt != null)
        {
            var imm =
                (InputMethodManager)Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(etxt.WindowToken, 0);
        }

        if (_prevFocusedView != null)
        {
            _prevFocusedView.ClearFocus();
        }
        _prevFocusedView = null;
    }
}
```

My Fragment

```
 public class FragmentTest : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment, container, false);
        var editText = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etxtInput);
        editText.Touch += editText_Touch;
        return view;
    }

    void editText_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        var etxtView = sender as EditText;
        if (etxtView != null)
        {
            var activity = Activity as MainActivity;
            if (activity != null)
            {
                activity.EditTextFieldClicked(this.View, sender as EditText);
            }
            etxtView.OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtInput"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```