# How to keep focus on Edittext after notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, textwatcher, notifydatasetchanged

Everytime I call `notifyDataSetChanged` in `beforeTextChanged` the focus of the edittext goes back to the first edittext inside the ListView.

Did you encounter this kind of error? If yes, can you please give me some advice on how to deal with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `editText.requestFocus()` to gain focus on `edittext` again

Comment: @Trivial, when i use `requestFocus()` after the `notifyDataSetChanged()` the last edittext in the listview was focused, not the current edittext.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161261/viewpager-focus-issue

Answer (score 0):

Remeber your selection before call `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
int position=mListView.getSelectedItemPosition();

notifyDataSetChanged ;

mListView.setSelection(position);

editText.requestFocus()
```

Comment: It works int the activity.Never tried in the adapter before.But i think it might alse work in the adapter