# EditText not showing when keyboard comes up

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have an issue with editext in my expandablelist view child.List moves up when the keyboard shown intially , but when i start typing list moves down and edittext not shown..

I have added

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in manifest file and its not working for me..any hope

Comment: Try to search similar questions here on stackoverflow. Some users solved the problem by replacing listview with scrollview and linearlayout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615436/when-the-soft-keyboard-appears-it-makes-my-edittext-field-lose-focus http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468765/buggy-listview-makes-me-sad

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not a good idea to have a EditText inside of a ListView. The keyboard coming up and repositioning of items doesn't work as expected on all devices and versions. But if you want to, use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This will relayout the items on the screen to make sure the item with focus is visible.