# EditText in Listview Strange selection behavior after scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a problem with EditText-fields in a listview. After i scroll some settings seem to be reset (selectAllOnFocus) and the selection cursor goes bananas.

I have a listview with a custom ArrayAdapter and a custom dataobject. In this case the object only holds one String (to simplify it).

My Activity

```
    // adapter + content
    List<ListviewObject> listViewContent = new ArrayList<ListviewObject>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        listViewContent.add(new ListviewObject("num: " + i));
    }       
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(AddNewPerson.this, R.layout.list_item, listViewContent);

    // list
    ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HolderObject holder = null;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new HolderObject();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HolderObject) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.lvObject = items.get(position);

    setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
// Retrieve the correct value 
    holder.name.setText(holder.lvObject.getName());

    return convertView;
}

public static class HolderObject {
    ListviewObject lvObject;
    TextView name;
}

private void setNameTextChangeListener(final HolderObject holder) {
    holder.name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// Update the value
            holder.lvObject.setName(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
```

To fix all the focusproblems I found in other threads I've set:
`.setItemsCanFocus(true)` on the listview
`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` in the activity XML
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest XML

Focussing and editing text works fine. When I scroll the correct values are held and all this seems to work fine.

Before I scroll and I click on some of the EditTexts this happens. (Last focused blurs, clicked one focuses, content is selected)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxfzm.jpg

After I scroll down and up again, and do the same clicks as before, this happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5oJX.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406472/edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-when-pressed-on-android-4-x see this link

Comment: as per my knowledge it is a bad practice to use edit text in list view

Comment: I see. So using TextView instead of EditText and replacing them on click/blur seems like the most viable option, or even reusing the convertView, but not the EditText inside it (recreate that on getView). I ran into more quirks in my final setup so I don't really feel like hacking my way through  some bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to listView recycling mechanism.  To know more about listview recycling mechanism you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

in your case you avoid the problem by storing a last focused editText and In getView set focus to only last stored integer and skip other position. hope this help you...

Comment: Decided to work around the problem as more than one thing went awry.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy:

1. Declare a `String[]` to keep track each `EditText`'s input inside the `afterTextChanged()` of `"addTextChangedListener()`.
2. Becareful of the order:

   ```
   viewHolder.editText.removeTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);

   viewHolder.textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
           mInputs[position] = editable.toString();            //record input

           viewHolder.editText.setSelection(viewHolder.editText.getText().length());       //set cursor to the end
       }
   };

   viewHolder.editText.addTextChangedListener(viewHolder.textWatcher);
   viewHolder.editText.setText(mInputs[position]);
   ```
3. Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your `Activity` in AndroidManifest file.

Good luck!