# Invisible EditText on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView basically with some TextViews on it. If a listitem is clicked, I change the visibility of the TextViews to GONE, and the visibility of an EditText to VISIBLE.

After that I want to focus on the EditText and show the keyboard. But if the keyboard comes up, the ListView will be redrawn, and the TextViews will be VISIBLE again, and the EditText GONE. I tried to show the keyboard in `getView()` too, but then the ListView will be several times redrawn.

How can I show the keyboard so, that the list won't be redrawn?

Comment: check this link ,  Hope help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406472/edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-when-pressed-on-android-4-x

Answer (score 2):

when keyboard appear then view port changed callback receive in onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) method 
and you can try setFocasable Item(true);