# EditText gaining focus but my typing doesn't append

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an EditText and have a hint. When I tap on the EditText, the keyboard appears, though, as I type neither the hint goes away nor my typing goes into view. It's like my input is going to /dev/null. My EditText is inside a ListView cell, if it helps. Here is my layout:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/aboutView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerFrame"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:hint="Tell something about yourself..." />
```

Why can this be?

Comment: Is the EditText getting the focus? I.e. is the blinking cursor appearing?

Comment: show the code xml got nothing to do with it

Comment: Please show the code and give us some information on the device you tested it. Have you tried different devices and/or emulator images?

Comment: @Msk well, it does get focus (the cursor initially displays, BUT then it disappears), the keyboard pops up (and it stays displayed even when cursor goes away too). Sometimes the cursor stays, and sometimes (very rarely) I can even type correctly. The seemingly-random occurance of the problem makes it difficult for me to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [EditText in Listview loses focus when pressed on Android 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406472/edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-when-pressed-on-android-4-x)

I don't know the exact reason, but I wasn't the only one suffering from `EditText` focus problems when inside a `ListView`. I've added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to my activity in manifest file and the problem went away.