# EditText Performance: Understanding GPU Process Time on Profile GPU Rendering

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext

I am investigating ways to improve performance in `EditText`, specifically in regards to load times. When loading large documents of a few thousand words or more, calling `setText` can freeze the UI for several seconds on some of my test devices and emulators.

In response, I have explored several possible solutions, none of which produce satisfactory results. I have tried to split large documents by paragraph, and load each paragraph into its own `RecyclerView` or `ListView` row. RecyclerView was completely hopeless due to a problem that [causes jerky scrolling](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82586). `ListView` provided great, almost immediate, load times, and pretty good scrolling (although not as a good as one `EditText` block) but there is an issue where `EditText` blocks inside rows [lose focus when selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406472/edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-when-pressed-on-android-4-x). I have also attempted to update an `EditText` in sections from `onProgressUpdate` in an `AsyncTask`, hoping that the user could interact with the text as it loads in sections, but load times are largely unaffected.

The most promising avenue I have explored relates to changing the following element in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I got the idea after watching the following segment from this [YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/VzYkVL1n4M8?t=3m25s) on the Google Developers channel. When I switched on GPU Profile rendering, I discovered that the orange bar (representing "process time") was rocketing every time `setText` was called. When I switched off hardware acceleration, `setText` performance increased massively, although other areas (like scrolling) became much worse.

What I would like to understand is - why is this happening? Also, is there a way that I can use this information to further increase performance? Can I toggle hardware acceleration off and on again programatically simply?

It's worth mentioning some devices, like a Nexus 7 2013 running API 22, don't suffer any issues whatsoever when calling setText on large documents, whereas others really struggle with hardware  acceleration on. I just want to understand what's going on better so I can attempt to fix it! Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is [a link to a GitHub Repository](https://github.com/PPartisan/ASyncEditText) for anyone to download one of my sample test apps to replicate the problems I listed above. I also have three videos I posted on the site demonstrating these issues, which I shall mirror below:

> I have made three video demonstrations that show this app running on a
> [Huawei Honor Holly running KitKat
> 4.4.2](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_honor_holly-6738.php) with the `hardwareAccelerated` attribute set to `true` in the
> `AndroidManifest`, then with the same phone with the same attribute
> set to `false`, and a separate [Nexus 7 (2013) running Lollipop
> 5.1](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_google_nexus_7_(2013)-5600.php) with hardware acceleration enabled. GPU Profiling is on in each case.
>
> [Honor Holly - Acceleration
> On](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEbWQtSjFUWFFNdWM/view?usp=sharing)
>
> [Honor Holly - Acceleration
> Off](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEX09aYzVSSENXZFU/view?usp=sharing)
>
> [Nexus 7 (2013) - Acceleration
> On](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEVkttRVN0RVlKN2c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You may wish to toss together a small sample app that demonstrates the phenomenon, then link to it from here.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added one of my test apps and a few videos of me using said app, to demonstrate the effects of calling `settext()` on a large file, and the effects on switching HW Acceleration on and off.

Comment: Oh, well, clearly your problem is too much alliteration in your device's name. :-) I'll try to give this a shot and see what I see.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on an HTC One M7 or a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900), both running 4.4. Both load the text in ~1 second and scroll fine thereafter. My best guess is that the problem is tied to the GPU used by your HHH, as the Mali-400mp2 seems to be [popular on lower-end devices](http://www.phonebunch.com/phone-filter/gpu/mali-400mp2/). I don't have a device with that GPU, though I may pick one up for testing purposes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for testing it. It's at least encouraging to know the problem is somewhat isolated.

Comment: @PPartisan Have you found a good solution to this performance issue? My editor struggles to keep up after only 300 lines, and I see those editing apps with rocking performance after 30k lines, there has to be a simple fix...

Comment: anyone found anything new about this issue?