# EditText inside ListView loses focus

Tags: android, listview

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In each row of the listview I have an EditText and when I click it, it is focused but immediatelly it loses the focus.

I have the property `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` in the activity in AndroidManifest. I have tried to add `adjustPan` and the focus works properly but in that case, the keyboard overlaps the list and I don't want that.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you updating accidentally the listview? Is there a call to notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Did you try  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ?

Comment: what if you programatically set focus in your getView() method when position is 0 ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406472/edittext-in-listview-loses-focus-when-pressed-on-android-4-x), I think it will solve your problem