# Android ListView with EditText loses AdjustPan

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have ListView with EditText in each row. My problem is when i click on the EditText then adjustPan is working (i mean EditText is above to softkeyboard), But when i start enter alphabets then EditText is Hiding with Keyboard.

Pls Help me...
Thanks a lot

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468765/buggy-listview-makes-me-sad

Comment: put it in a relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in manifest file:

```
      <activity 
              android:name=".MyEditTextInListView"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

in Your activity which hold listview.

Comment: this is manifest file acivity code:  <activity
            android:name="com.ril.rpos.SaleRefundTxnActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>

Comment: want your complete Manifest file ?