# ListView + EditText => bad keyboard behavior

Tags: android

I am using a ListView with some EditTexts in the items, and with a floating action bottom (fab) at the bottom of the screen (over the list view).

What I want when I select an EditView and the keyboard appears over it:

- the ListView is scrolled to show the EditView.
- the fab stays at the bottom of the screen.
- nothing else.

What I get :

- the list view is not scrolled to the item, the keyboard does not target the touched EditText, it targets nothing (the keyboard opens in the good input mode then resets).
- the fab moves aligned to the keyboard instead of being covered.

I tried the option `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`, then the fab stays at the bottom as expected, but the listView doesn't scroll to the editText. The keyboard is targeting the good EditText. It is almost good except I would need to re implement the scrolling to the item.

I tried the option `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, then the whole screen is moved up, which is not the expected behavior.

Is there actually a solution for that or should I stick to the "not great but at least functional" adjustPan ?

Comment: could you add some screens?

Comment: It is not recommended to use editable views in lists beacuse of recycling. Google recommends to have immutable list and edit activity for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView don't do well with editable views, because the inner views get redrawn once or mutiple times, causing multiple focus events.

This happens since '10, so I don't expect a fix any time soon. I work arounded the issue.

[Buggy ListView makes me sad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468765/buggy-listview-makes-me-sad)

Comment: Technically. this is why the `RecyclerView` introduced in Android 5.0 was redesigned.

Comment: There is the same issue with the RecyclerView

Comment: ...oh. Well that is problematic.