# EditText.setMovementMethod with LinkMovement Method in ListView - loses ability to "Click" on rows in the list

Tags: android, listview

So, basically I have a custom View that contains a ListView with a custom Adapter that has the ability to read in information from the network (dumbed down HTML) and display it on a row by row basis.

All of this works, but I need the text that is read in to be parsed as HTML which contains links that can be tapped on and launched in browser.

I managed to do this by:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(textBuffer), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Works great, any `<a href=""></a>` links in the text are displayed as links and can be tapped.

This is a side effect of now making it so the rest of the rows in the ListView cannot be tapped (or tapped and held).  Basically, all the rows are non-selectable now.

Is there any way to achieve both of what I need?

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting text.setFocusable(false). By removing focus from the EditText, events will be passed onto the ListView or other items.

Comment: Still no dice.  If I have a long block of text in the textBuffer with a few HTML links, the links are still clickable, but if I push (and hold) anywhere on the text without the link, it still doesn't "select (turn yellow)".

Basically, I need to keep the default behavior of being able to long-press the row (for my context menu), but if there are links in there, to launch them in the browser.

Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score -1):

When you put an item that is focusable inside a ListView, it automatically makes the ListView not focusable.  This is the behavior you are seeing.

To make them both focusable, I believe you can adjust the [descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability) property of the ListView.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview) for a similar problem.