# Focus of EditText moves when ListView is scrolled

Tags: listview, android-edittext, focus

I have a `ListView` in which I have a `EditText` in each item of the list.

When I click on the `EditText` and scroll the `ListView` the focus of the `EditText` moves to some other item's `EditText`.

Why is this happening and could someone help in stopping this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Add the else part to your convertView code inside getView method.

```
if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (((ListView)parent).getSelectedItemPosition() == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        parent.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

A similar query is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623999/edittext-keeps-focus-when-keyboard-up-and-scrolling-the-listview)