# Android EditText values

Tags: android

I am dynamically generating `EditText`  box according to the user input. How can I store all the values in array list. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please give a better description of your question and post some code to help us help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918320/dynamically-add-textviews-to-a-linearlayout See selected answer and comments related to it. this is your complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> arryList = new ArrayList<String>();  
arryList.add(editText.getText().toString);
```

this should help..