# How to dynamically create layouts in android studio depending upon the user's input?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

So I'm trying to make an event organization app. The user needs to be able to manage multiple events at the same time. So, if he clicks on 'add event', I must be able to dynamically create a new layout folder for that respective event. How do I go about doing so?

Comment: No, you can't create a layout folder/file programmatically.. .but you can inflate a already built layout based on different user input.

Comment: Thank you! What exactly is the difference between gradle flavors and this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to "dynamically create a new layout folder for that respective event" but according to your requirement u can generate views dynamically according to your requirement or inflate a layout

(inflate layout)
1>[How to inflate one view with a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335813/how-to-inflate-one-view-with-a-layout)

generate view dynamically from code
2>[Dynamically add textViews to a linearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918320/dynamically-add-textviews-to-a-linearlayout)

Hope this may help you

Comment: What if my layout had many different fragments in it such as a camera fragment and so on?

Comment: U want to generate a view containing Textview etc multiple time so that u can create multiple events at a single click