# Cannot type anythig into the editText field that is inside listview(that is edittext field is the cell of the listview)

Tags: android

hii
   I  have a listview and each cell of a listview contain an edittext field.But the problem is i can't type anything into the editText field.I there any solution ?

Comment: please post your code along with layout files associated with it.

Comment: What do you mean? No keyboard is shown? Or symbols are not printed in editText?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview - see the answer to that question for your answer.

Comment: symbols are not printed in editText.

Answer (score 0):

EditText fields may be disabled due to layout_width and layout_height done for EditTexts and ListView.

Comment: I set layout_width and layout_height same for both editText and listview