# EditText focus lost

Tags: android

In a custom ListView, there are two columns, one contains a TextView and the other a EditText component.To enter some preferences, as the user clicks on the EditText, the software keyboard comes in focus but focus from the EditText is lost. How I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Answer (score 4):

For editText use method setFocusable(false).
For textView use setFocusable(true).

Also write a listener on focus lost for both textView and editText:

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
           //do job here when EditText loses focus
        }
    }
});
```