# EditText not allowing for editing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` which has three rows. The last 2 rows have `EditText` fields which allow for editing. I have the xml for those two below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_message_subject_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_message_details_subject"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason when I click on the `EditText`, it just simply loses the cursor, but the keyboard is still visible. I'm not sure but it happens on both boxes. There is no `TouchListener` or any other listener for that matter. Is there something special about putting inside of a `ListView` that I need to be aware of?

**EDIT**

When I put the following in my manifest.xml file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I see that it works...however the `ListView` won't scroll when the text goes below the keyboard. Is there a way to take care of that use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something special about putting inside of a ListView that I need to be aware of?

Yes, remember that the `ListView` wants to handle focus and click events, but now you have an `EditText` in the mix. Check out the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272140/edittext-in-listview-android).

However, if you only have 3 rows in your `ListView`, you really aren't gaining much by using it. `ListView` is designed to recycle views and be very efficient when you have many items in your list. If you only have a few rows, I'd suggest using a `ScrollView` and adding your `View`s (rows) to it, and simply handle the `onClick` events yourself (if your list items are clickable).

Comment: Can't do that because it may change later. But I made some progress...just not done yet.