# Spinner inside custom ListView freezes on returning from another activity

Tags: android, listview, spinner, freeze

Hello all here is my problem.
My app's listview (which is inside a tab widget) contains various types of rows. I have had many problems setting this up and here is another 1. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467421/edittext-settext-changes-my-softkeyboard-input-type-in-a-custom-adapter) for the code, which basically remains the same.
I use another activity (a custom implemented ES file explorer) which is a filebrowser dialog to open a file. The data from the file is sent to the listview.
When it shows the list and I click on the spinner the screen darkens and freezes. If I press the back button the darkening disappears, the listview becomes clickable but the spinner still is not. The only way out is if I flip to another tab widget and back again (there are 2 separate ones) the spinner will work again.

I should say that the spinner works just fine if I do not load files from the other activity. 
So I guess in other words there is a problem of focus or something when switching and killing activities.

I hope you can help.

EDIT
after some more trying, sometimes after loading the file from the browser it will return to a black screen where the listview is there but not visible.
eg you can click on it and the editor opens.

Answer (score 0):

Hi well again it took ages but here was the problem.
the custom listview had

```
this.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

set

so all I had to do was set

```
holder.techniquespinner.setDescendantFocusability(parent.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

for the spinner and voila; I haven't tried but it should probably go in the xml file.

Thanks to anybody who looked.

EDIT
Crap I spoke to soon. It still doesn't work.
There is 2 tabwidgets inside a flipper.
If returning from the browser to the tab where it left WITHOUT flipping the flipper it works.
Flip once, back again and then to the browser does not work.
I'm not even sure what code to post. It is quite complex.

FINAL EDIT

This is how I fixed it.

```
flipper.showNext();
```

and then back again.

It somehow refreshes the view brings it back to focus and useable again.

It isn't pretty but it works.