# EditText focus in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` and in that `ListView` I have a Row with some `TextViews` and `EditTexts` in it.
When I press anywhere on the row I want the `EditText` to take focus so text can be entered.

The problem is that I cannot get this to work. When i place the `EditText` in the `ListView` the `OnItemClick` will not respond when I click on the `ListView`.

I tried using `focusable="false"` on the `EditText` and it allowed me to click on the `ListView` again but I could not get the `EditText` to get focus even after setting the focusable to true.
Next I tried using the `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` in the `ListView` but it did not seem to make any change, it still wouldn't work.

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it should let you click on a line and focus the EditText (modified from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680077/1105376)):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) 
{ 
    EditText yourEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.youredittextid);
    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS); 
    yourEditText.requestFocus(); 
} 

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> listView) 
{ 
    // onNothingSelected happens when you start scrolling, so we need to prevent it from staying 
    // in the afterDescendants mode if the EditText was focused  
    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

do like this

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListViewId);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
listView.setClickable(false);
```

ie,

after getting the listview object from xml, disable the click on this listview and pass the focus to the child views

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property as `enabled="false"` in the xml row layout, and on the onItemClickListener you can `setEnabled(true)` and then `setFocusable(true)` , this should solve it.