# MVVMCross Databinding Lists with EditText

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've been playing with the monodroid/monotouch for a while now and having decided to jump from monocross to mvvmcross, I've hit a bit of a problem.

I have a domain model which contains a sub property which is a list of another domain object. Has-Many if you will. What I'm trying to do is display the aggregate root object and allow the user to fill in the details of the sub object.

```
public class objA
{
    public List<objB> mySubObjs
}
```

I pretty easily got this hooked up using the MvxBindableListView. Except I couldn't bind to objA.mySubObjs, I had to bring the list up a level in the ViewModel and bind to that? Anyway, the issue I faced is that my itemtemplate for the List looked a bit like this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="a)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        <EditText xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/x.x.x.x"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            local:MvxBind="{&apos;Text&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;Name&apos;}}" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Which renders fine, but is just not useable. When I click on the editText control is brings up the softkeyboard and in doing so loses focus. I've read a couple of articles about EditText in ListView's don't work too well.

Therefore I tried building up the List view manually by binding to specific items i.e. objA.mySubObjs[0].Name, but this doesn't seem to reflect back in the ViewModel.

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        local:MvxBind="{&apos;Text&apos;:{&apos;Path&apos;:&apos;Items[0].Name&apos;}}" />
```

I'm at a bit of a loss and didn't really want to go down the route of flattening the List within my ViewModel to accomodate the Android View.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Does this help - [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

> . Except I couldn't bind to objA.mySubObjs,

on other points, feel free to ask this as a separate question - it should be possible...