# How to find out what part of an item in ListView was touched?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a `ListView` showing in each row three things (left icon, middle text, right icon). When the user "clicks" on a row, I want to do an action depending on the horizontal position of the "click", but there's no x-coordinate in `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` nor do I have any idea what to do instead.

I don't need the exact coordinate, an information like "left/middle/right" would suffice. Knowing which of the three things was touched is about the same. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview), but I doubt it's related. *Is it? Is there a way how to get the x-coordinate?*

Or should I try `GridLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the exact coordinates of a click, you need to set [`onTouchListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead on the view that you want receive events for.

From this, you'll get the [`MotionEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) which you can use to figure out the coordinates and pretty much anything else you'd want to know.

Comment: Works like charm... I only save the `event.getX() / view.getWidth()` into a global variable and later in `onItemClick` use it to decide what to do.