# Number keyboard not showing on Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to implement a number-only EditText field in my app (Android API 23), meaning that I want the number-only keyboard to show-up when the user enters into it.

To do this I have tried setting these attributes on the EditText field...

```
android:inputType="number"

android:digits="1234567890"
```

and

```
android:inputType="phone"

android:digits="1234567890"
```

but this still brings up the full keyboard.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm testing on a Nexus 5x (Android 6.0.1) with the default keyboard

Comment: Did you try just with `android:inputType="number"` and without `android:digits="1234567890"`? That's working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is I had the EditText inside a ListView.  Which is problematic for some reason.
I fixed it by setting the ListView like this

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

This helped me lead to the answer
[EditText inside ListView will not stay focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730610/edittext-inside-listview-will-not-stay-focused)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
   <EditText
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this programatically.
Try doing:

```
inputType = TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
```

or

```
inputType = TYPE_NUMBER_PHONE
```

The first one is for number only. The second is for numbers who have the phone number format.