# Android, is there any way to disable writing inside a date picker using keyboard?

Tags: android, datepicker

Is there any way to disable writing inside a date picker using keyboard? As I just want the plus and minus signs to be used to set the date.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you planning on breaking default user interaction? Expected behavior does not work anymore and it will confuse and/or annoy your users...

Comment: Because I have constrains on the input date from the user

Comment: So check if the input date is conform your constraints after the user choose a new date, and notify the user when it is not...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
myDatePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for DatePickerDialog, if API level is lower than 11?

Comment: Not sure let me try it out later today when I get a chance

Comment: @Antigona try this:
myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

Answer (score 5):

```
dp.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

is the best way to do so.

You can check this also

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();

            int Year = DatePicker.getYear();
            int Month = DatePicker.getMonth();
            int Day = DatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

            start.set(Year, Month, Day);
    //      DayDatePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

            Date periodDate = start.getTime();
            int daysToAdd = 280;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,daysToAdd );
            System.err.println("-----" +cal.getTime());
            int AfterCalc = cal.getTime().getYear()+1900;
            System.err.println("-----" + AfterCalc);
            int AfterCalc2 = cal.getTime().getMonth();
            System.err.println("----" + AfterCalc2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option for stopping manual editing in **DatePickerDialog** items is using set the **descendantFocusability** . You can add it in code or in your dialog style file.

[Here is the implementation using style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516738/4661315)