# alertDialog - datepicker don't allow to change the date shown

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with alertDialog to manage a datepicker.
the problem is simple:
[image]

I don't want that u can click on the date (in this case just years) and change the value.
i want just that u can select one of the years showed.

**SOLVED**:
solution:

```
myDatePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

source:
[Disable keyboard input on Android TimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391216/disable-keyboard-input-on-android-timepicker)

Comment: I think you have to change your title with this : Disable keyboard input on Android DatePicker

Comment: Possibility duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471688/android-is-there-any-way-to-disable-writing-inside-a-date-picker-using-keyboard