# issue with expandable listview setOnChildClickListener

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am developing application with expandable listview and get display data in this listview very well,but problem is with `setOnChildClickListener` which is not working. there are no interactive widget(checkbox or edittex)which cause the issue of focus and we need to false the focus ,no there are not I have taken Texview only in Parent list as well as in child. I have also tried with do that all texview `focusable as false` but not getting success.can you please solve this

code :

```
mlvInstructionlist = (ExpandableListView)amviInstruction. findViewById(R.id.lvInsListofInstruction);
        AssetsWiseInstructionListAdapter adapter = new AssetsWiseInstructionListAdapter(getActivity(),mlvInstructionlist, mlstGroupCollection);

        mlvInstructionlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        mlvInstructionlist.setOnChildClickListener(this);
@Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Child click Header",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         AppLog.showLogI(TAG, "Child click Header");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what does your class signature look like? did you `implements OnChildClickListener`?

Comment: yes its implemented `OnChildClickListener`

Comment: yes but thing is i am do it in fragment may be is there any issue with fragment

Comment: then do it in your adapter.

Comment: How can i do that , let me give you adapter

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace your listView with a scrollView. This should resolve it or try and refer this post : [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview).

This talks about setting the onClick and focussable for the descendants.