# CrossUI.Droid.Dialog EntryElement loses focus with text prediction

Tags: autocomplete, focus, xamarin.android, android-dialog, mvvmcross

I'm creating a new Dialog view in Droid platform, using the `CrossUI.Droid.Dialog` project. I'm also using bindings provided by the MvvmCross Framework.

Here is the code I have in the Droid view, to create and bind the Dialog:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        DroidResources.Initialise(typeof(Resource.Layout));

        Root = new RootElement()
            {
                new Section("Private Configuration")
                    {
                        new EntryElement("Name:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Name'}}"),
                        new EntryElement("Description:").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.PrivateDescription'}}"),
                        new BooleanElement("Active?").Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Configuration.Active'}}")
                    },
                new Section("Display Configuration")
                    {
                        new StringElement("Header Title")
                            {
                                Click = (o, e) => GoToHeaderTitleActivity(),
                                LayoutName = "dialog_rootNavigate"
                            }
                    }
            };
    }
```

When I run the app, the dialog is shown and the bindings are correct.

**The problem I have is when I try to write something in one of the EntryElement, the focus just goes somewhere else... This only happens when I have 'Text Prediction' enabled.**

I've checked the sample in [Android.Dialog](https://github.com/slodge/Android.Dialog) and all seems to work just fine.

I'm using a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, with ICS 4.0

Does anyone had this problem?

Comment: "Does anyone had this problem?" is not a very good question for StackOverflow - it's better to ask "How can I stop the TextView from losing focus?". Also I'm not sure this problem is to do with mvvmcross or Dialog - looks like it's more to with TextView's in general - maybe better asking this as a question about Android TextViews rather than as something as specialised as "mvvmcross" and "android-dialog". e.g. "I've got an Android TextView in one case that loses focus, how can I stop it happening?" Good luck!

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I've added some debugging to the droid.dialog stuff and this is what happens when you try to select a TextEdit: https://gist.github.com/wayne-o/8179431 I guess that is why we are losing focus?

Comment: And I can confirm that this does not happen when you select a text edit on the touch dialog.

Comment: I can also confirm this happens on the Sony Experia E and my HTC sensation. On GenyMotion (and i'm guessing the emulator) it does still happen but the text view doesn't lose focus - I'm guessing because it has the resources to handle all the getview calls and not lose track? I don't know for sure but this makes the droid.dialog stuff pretty unusable. I am trying to find a fix but if anyone can chip in I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!!

Apparently there is a known issue in Android where EditText controls and ListView don't play nice. This is not a problem with MvvmCross or Monodroid.Dialog.

To overcome this (and I'm guessing this is the reason for it's existence?) use the `MvxLinearDialogActivity` when developing forms using dialog. The issue instantly disappears.

As the comment in the class says:

> DialogActivity based on a linear view, this will solve all edittext related focus problems when using elements 
>    suggestions at [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview) doesn't help for example