# Android AutoCompleteTextView as ListView header

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to set an AutoCompleteTextView as a ListView header, but if I do so the autocomplete box never appears. The code for creating the auto complete view comes directly from the [Hello, AutoComplete](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) tutorial in googles docs. The COUNTRIES array also comes from there.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ResultList);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TableLayout searchHeader = (TableLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_header, null); 
myList.addHeaderView(searchHeader, null, false);

final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) myList.findViewById(R.id.edit);
ArrayAdapter<String> searchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
textView.setThreshold(1);

        //Dummy data for listview.

String[] listContent = {
        "test", "test", "test", "test",
        "test", "test", "test", "test"
};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new SearchResultAdapter(this, listContent);
myList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

As a test, I added a TextChangedListener to try and force show the dialog

```
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textView.showDropDown();
        }
    });
```

The dialog appears but is closed almost instantly. I wonder if some kind of event bubbling from the list view is causing this?

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046302/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-with-listview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview) regarding focus of EditText views within a ListView & some reading of the AutoCompleteTextView source helped me find the answer. Setting the order of focus on the ListView to afterDescendants allowed the dialog to be shown normally.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ResultList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Words cannot express the joy haha!

Answer (score 0):

use  in your XML file with autocompletetextview may be it will help