# getting View for ListView item / reverse order on 2.2; works on 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-adapter

I have a ListView which shows items from ArrayAdapter. I want to animate the view when it is cliked.
The problem is that on different versions of android I am getting different views (see below)

I'm getting the view from ListActivity using this method :

```
private View getViewForListPosition(int position) {

    int firstPosition = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition() - mList.getHeaderViewsCount();
    int wantedChild = position - firstPosition;

    ZLog.d(LOG,"getViewForListPosition , position : " + position + ", wantedChild : " + wantedChild + ", view hash : " +mList.getChildAt(wantedChild).hashCode());

    for(int i = mList.getChildCount(); i>0; i--){
        ZLog.d(LOG, "pos : " + (i-1) + ", hash : " +mList.getChildAt(i-1).hashCode());
    }

    return mList.getChildAt(wantedChild);
}
```

So that on Android 4.0.3 & 4.2.2 phone I get :

```
getViewForListPosition , position : 3, wantedChild : 3, view hash : 1101734248

pos : 5, hash : 1104109360
pos : 4, hash : 1104254936
pos : 3, hash : 1101734248
pos : 2, hash : 1104876880
pos : 1, hash : 1104862296
pos : 0, hash : 1104793008
```

then when item is clicked my adapter `getView` method runs for each view :

```
getView, position : 0, convertView is notnull, cv hash1104793008
getView, position : 1, convertView is notnull, cv hash1104862296
getView, position : 2, convertView is notnull, cv hash1104876880
getView, position : 3, convertView is notnull, cv hash1101734248
getView, position : 4, convertView is notnull, cv hash1104254936
getView, position : 5, convertView is notnull, cv hash1104109360
```

so you can see everything is fine and works as expected.
However when I run this on Android 2.2 these are the results I am getting :

```
getViewForListPosition , position : 3, wantedChild : 3, view hash : 1205607672

pos : 5, hash : 1205730120
pos : 4, hash : 1205712904
pos : 3, hash : 1205607672
pos : 2, hash : 1206547728
pos : 1, hash : 1206483960
pos : 0, hash : 1207864856

getView, position : 0, convertView is notnull, cv hash1205730120
getView, position : 1, convertView is notnull, cv hash1205712904
getView, position : 2, convertView is notnull, cv hash1205607672
getView, position : 3, convertView is notnull, cv hash1206547728
getView, position : 4, convertView is notnull, cv hash1206483960
getView, position : 5, convertView is notnull, cv hash1207864856
```

so as you might have noticed `getViewForListPosition` will give me back the view which adapter uses for position 2

You might have also noticed that either the `Adapter.getView` or `ListView.getChildAt` is returning items in reverse order which causes this issue. What could be the reason for this behaviour? (I'm not doing anything fancy in my adapter)

I will be thankful for any kind of hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. so this is what is happening :

On a clean `ListView` When I register `onItemClickListener` and perform clicks adapter `getView` method for views is not called. This is what I would expect.

If I set a `mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` this makes `getView` methods run right after click is registered. This is also what is expected.

However the difference between 2.2 and 4+ versions is that :
on 2.2 : when this refresh happens `getView` operates on a reversed list of views (see my question)
on 4+ (possibly API 11+) : `getView` operates on normal order of list

What is the most interesting part is that when I delay call to getViewForListPosition by 10ms everything works fine and adapter has proper list of views (normal order again). So it seems that the order of views is reversed only during adapter refresh with `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`

To solve this problem I dont change listview mode to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` so that adapter doesn't fire during click. I set bg/graphics for clicked item on my own inside `onItemClicked`

hope that it saves someone some time :)

Comment: Note that the issue experienced in 2.2 is also present in 2.3