# ListView strange behavior

Tags: android

Here is what I do in `onCreateView` (in fragment):

```
NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsList, R.layout.news_list_item);
newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

And here is `onItemClick`:

```
@Override                                                                         
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_back_selected);
}
```

And the problem is when I tap on the first item then the last visible is only highlighted. On the 2nd - 1st and 2nd from the end. 3rd - 2nd, last and 3rd from the end etc.
I checked that `view` is a really the item was clicked by looking inside `mChild` array. Currently I can't figure out the reason. Do you have any ideas? Let me know if more datailed code is required. Thanks in advance.
The application was tested on 10 inches tablet emulator, Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` attribute of the listview fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats it but it seems like the same issue that I have encountered some time ago :

[getting View for ListView item / reverse order on 2.2; works on 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783089/getting-view-for-listview-item-reverse-order-on-2-2-works-on-4-0-3)

try wraping it in Runnable

something like :

```
view.post(new Runnable(
   run(){
      view.setBackground...
   }
))
```

Comment: Unfortunally didn't help. But thanks for the link it reminded me about the `android:choiceMode` that I tried before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you affect the new background to tell the adapter that you want to refresh the view.