# When i focus on edit text with numeric input type, standart qwerty keyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-edittext, numeric-keypad

I have set my `EditText` field like this:

```
   <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

When I click on that `Edittext`, correct numeric input keyboard shows up, but then immediately is replaced by the standard keyboard. If I click again, numeric keyboard appears and is not replaced by the standard keyboard. This happens in dynamically generated `ListView`, if that affects anything, and happens in both the emulator and the phone (samsung galaxy note). How can I prevent the standard keyboard from appearing?

Here is the actual code:

```
public class Delivery extends Activity {
ListView deliveryTipes;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.delivery_main);
    deliveryTipes=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.tasksID);
    String[] deliveryTipesList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tasks);
    deliveryTipes.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.delivery_line,R.id.taskName, deliveryTipesList));
}
```

}

delivery_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tasksID" android:layout_gravity="center" android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

delivery_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Task Name"
        android:id="@+id/taskName" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textStyle="bold"/>
<Space
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/space"/>
<EditText

        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I noticed that Android doesn't like having EditText inside a ListView line. If you can redesign your program to have EditText separately (e.g. you click a ListView line and get an EditText in a dialog) it should work.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2680077/315306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of problems are very annoying. The short story is that by default a `ListView` is meant to simply show items, and optionally select them.

`ListView` doesn't assume its children to be focusable, it handles the focus by itself and triggers the appropriate listeners. When you start putting focusable widgets in a `ListView`, things soon get wild. Post the actual code, and you'll have more chances to get help.