# Android how do I stop the screen from scrolling to top when user types something on keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have some edittexts in a scrollview. When a user clicks on them the keyboard shows up and sometimes it covers the edittext. The user can scroll the half of the screen that shows the page to the edittext but the minute the user types something it immediately scrolls to the top obscuring the edittext again.

How do I get this to stop?

Also for what it's worth the scrollview has

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in it's XML.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` for scrollview and it should work!

Link1 :
[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview/2680077#2680077)

Link2 :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680077/1556997

Comment: The descentfocusability is not working. Is it because I'm adding the views programmatically