# Focust on ListView item (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with my ListView. ListView row contains: TextView field, EditText field and Image field but focused only on EditText field. If I write in Layout attributes `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` then ListView row becomes focusable, but EditText field becomes not focusable. What should I do to get focusable ListView row and EditText field in this row?

Here is the example of my MainActivity layout with ListView and ListView row layout.

MainActivity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:text="@string/button_select_folder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_select_folder"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp" >
        </Button>
        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvPathToPL"
            android:text="@string/tvPathToPL"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/btnPathToPL"
            android:text="@string/btnPathToPL"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/tlPLName">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tvPLName"
                    android:text="@string/tvPLName"/>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/etPLName"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:hint="@string/etPLName"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <Button
            android:text="@string/generate_playlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/generate"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_weight="0">
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/ExitApp"
            android:text="@string/ExitApp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<!-- android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants -->
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL_Option"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OptionDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/OptionSongCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/OptionImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Will be very thankful for help.

Comment: either entire ListItem can be focusable or EditText in list item is focusable. you can't get focus for both.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2680077/1289716) will help you answer