# ListView OnItemLongClickListener() not triggered

Tags: java, android, listview, contextual-action-bar

I have a class that extends ListActivity where the list items respond to OnClick events. Adding an OnItemLongClickListener does not work. The onItemLongClick() function is not called (no log-output or Toast showing) but the normal OnClick() event is handled instead.

I want to display a contextual action bar upon long click. A minimum example using my code in a new project works fine. So my question is: What can possibly prevent the onItemLongClick() trigger from being triggered?

My minimum API is 11. I am also setting the listView to `longClickable="true"`.

**Activity code (selected functions):**

```
public class EventListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<Event> arrEvents = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<Event> adpEvents = null;

    private ActionMode mActionMode = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // only create list adapter and set it
        arrEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
        adpEvents = new ArrayAdapter<Event>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, android.R.id.text1, arrEvents) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                text1.setText(arrEvents.get(position).getTitle());
                text2.setText(arrEvents.get(position).getDateTimeFormatted());
                return view;
            }
        };

        setListAdapter(adpEvents);

        // add CAB to ListView
        setupCAB();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // populate list and refresh adapter
        createEventList();
        adpEvents.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // if list empty show emtpy msg, otherwise hide it
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_list);
        TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_empty);
        if(arrEvents.isEmpty()) {
            empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    private void setupCAB() {
        // Important: to select single mode
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            // Called when the user long-clicks an item on the list
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int position, long rowid) {
                Log.w("EventListActivity", "Long click detected!");
                Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "Long click detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (mActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Important: to mark the editing row as activated
                getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

                // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
                mActionMode = EventListActivity.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.event_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user enters the action mode
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Disable the list to avoid selecting other elements while editing one
            EventListActivity.this.getListView().setEnabled(false);
            return true; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnu_share_event:
                //TODO share event
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Re-enable the list after edition
            EventListActivity.this.getListView().setEnabled(true);
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };

}
```

**activity_event_list.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".EventListActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:longClickable="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a ListActivity or ListFragment there is no method you can override for the long-click, and getting access to the ListView is not possible in onCreateView(), since it is being controlled by the parent class.

So, to overcome this, I did this, since the getListView() command won't work until after the view is created:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecipeListView = this.getListView();
    mRecipeListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long row_id) {
            // Process the long-click
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is in your last sentence **"since the getListView() command won't work until after the view is created"** ---> I called my `setupCAB()` method before calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_list);` so the list view was not available yet. Where I should have put your code I still don't understand though...

Answer (score 5):

If you have buttons responding to `onClick()` events inside your listview, you need to set the following in the container holding those buttons:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

If what you have are textviews, the problem is slightly trickier. See this: [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview/2680077#2680077)

Comment: Thanks but I don't have buttons or EditText views inside my ListView. Just normal TextViews (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2`) like I posted in the question.

Comment: Did you try adding the blocksDescendants anyway?

Comment: Yes but it did not change anything as my problem was of a different origin (see my comment on Rick Falck's answer).

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not solve user1's question but the symptoms were similar my problem (i.e. `OnItemClickListener` was getting called but `OnItemLongClickListener` was not). I'm posting my answer here in case anyone else stumbles on this question like I did when trying to solve my problem.

I was using a ListView inside a Fragment and implemented the listener methods:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,
        OnLongClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {
```

Here is the `onItemClick` method that was working fine:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long rowId) {

    Log.i("Chimee", "short click working");

}
```

And here is the `onItemLongClick` method that wasn't firing:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long rowId) {

    Log.i("Chimee", "Long click working");
    return false;
}
```

Of course the simple answer was that I forgot to `setOnItemLongClickListener`. I added it after the `setOnItemClickListener` that I had all along and then it worked fine.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    lvSuggestions = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSuggestions);
    lvSuggestions.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    lvSuggestions.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    lvSuggestions.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); // Forgot this

    ...
}
```