# how to reaching to the values in group of edit text in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `Listview` content form `TextView` and `Edittext`, and I want to get the value from each `Edittext` in this `Listview`.

My problems are:
When the `Listview` is created, the focus is not on the first `Edittext` in `Listview`.

The second problem, is when I enter a value in `Edittext` and move list text down in screen the value in `Edittext` changed or removed, or the value moved to another `Edittext` on screen.

You can see image in this
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5umrRHnugXBbG1xNk9jVzFxbFU/edit?usp=sharing)

my code is

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AllStudent ;
    AllStudent = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int j=0; j<15; j++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put("id"," " + j);
        map.put("name", "A" + j ); 
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        AllStudent.add(map);
    }
   listadapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            sc_grade_group.this, AllStudent,
            R.layout.list_item_graed, new String[] { "id","name"  },
            new int[] { R.id.list_itemGra_t1, R.id.list_itemGra_t2 });
    setListAdapter(listadapter); 



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_t1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_t2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_2"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_t4"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_2"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/gold"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:background="@color/cachecolor2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_Degree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_t3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"
        android:background="@color/cachecolor2" >

    </LinearLayout>

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_itemGra_t5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you **joao2fast4u**  for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, if you want that entered information should be persistent when scrolled out and scrolled back, you have to make a model that should store what was entered. All information is cleared when you scroll, and scroll back is because ListView re-creates only those view's which are on screen and visible.

Used SimpleAdapter can hook up with ViewBinder interface, though its hard to handle storing in there. My suggestion would be to make a class model and make a custom adapter for this.

Here is a great tutorial on various ListView implementations (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Second problem, to prevent the view focusing once you enter the area, you can try setting 
seting the attributes android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" on EditText, though this should be tested, im not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1, Try in onCreate:

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {                                   // run when focus is lost
            String value = v.getText().toString();         // get the value from the EditText
            // Your code to update hashmap
        }
    }
});
```

2, When you create the **ListView**, add a **OnFocusChangeListener**, like shown below

```
myList.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            myHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myList.setSelection(0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and if it wont work read [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)