# Expandable listview - disable recycling of views

Tags: android, expandablelistview, recycle

I am using an Expandable listview in Android and having huge problems with interactive EditTexts within the child items due to Android's recycle policy.

I was wondering if I could somehow disable this recycling (there won't be too many elements there, so performance shouldn't be an issue)?

The problem is that there are duplicates in the EditTexts, i.e. if I type in something in the first EditText, it is possible that in some other EditText the same text appears, or if I collapse and expand a group, the strings in the EditTexts often get mixed up.

Following my code:

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    String comment = "";
    state = getStatelist().get(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ChildHolder();           
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem_list_item, parent, false);
        holder.title = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);          
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(state.commentList != null){
        holder.title.setText(state.commentList[childPosition]);
    }
    else{
        holder.title.setText("");
    }

    holder.title.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            state = getStatelist().get(groupPosition);

            state.commentList[childPosition] = s.toString();                

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}


public class States {

  public String code = "";
  public String name = "";
  public String[] commentList;
 }
```

Comment: Simply ignoring the non null `convertView`(building the row views each time) doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't; since I am using EditTexts, duplicate entries appear when I don't use the viewHolder pattern.

Comment: I don't see how you would have duplicates if you properly set the data. I was only talking about the convertView and not the ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: If you want to have EditText fields, do not use ListViews. Use LinearLayouts instead. It is as simple as that.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview  . I've seen that you deleted that line which was wrong:)

Comment: @PhilipSheard I need Expandable Listviews with EditTexts as children. I suppose using ListViews to accomplish that is rather difficult?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different problems. What you want is to clear up the values of the edittexts in every rebuild. So you can change

```
  if(state.commentList != null){
        holder.title.setText(state.commentList[childPosition]);
    }
    else{
        holder.title.setText("");
    }
```

into

```
holder.title.setText("");
  if(state.commentList != null){
        holder.title.setText(state.commentList[childPosition]);
    }
```

Now if what you really really want is to remove view recycling, just make convertview always reinflate

```
state = getStatelist().get(groupPosition);
holder = new ChildHolder();           
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childitem_list_item, parent, false);
holder.title = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);          
convertView.setTag(holder);
holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
// You can remove the viewholder pattern because you're not using it anymore
if(state.commentList != null){
```

Comment: Interesting, inflating the view every time seems to work, but now I have to touch the EditText twice until it gets focus. How come?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer that question as it is.

Comment: If I simply inflate the view every time, when I click on one of the EditTexts, the cursor appears for a short time, then the keyboard appears and the EditText loses focus. Then I have to touch the EditText again to type stuff in.

Comment: I don't know how your layout, activity/fragment or touch/edittext listeners are and I cannot infer it from a description of the behaviour.

Comment: My layout doesn't contain anything interesting, just regular settings, nothing like "android:beforeDescdencants" or anything, the only EditText listener is the one I posted in my question (addTextChangeListener).