# Edittext inside listview losing focus

Tags: android, listview

I have some TextViews and edittexts in a listview item.

What i want is to show some items, quantity,rate and total price...

Whenever quantity or rate is changed, total price also should be changed...
Listitem should seen as selected when edittext is focussed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MySimpleArrayAdapterNew sampleListAdapter;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sampleArrayList;
private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    sampleArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    HashMap<String, String> sampleObjectMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sampleObjectMap.put("value1", "aaa"+i);

    sampleObjectMap.put("value2", "666");
    sampleObjectMap.put("value3", "1");
    sampleObjectMap.put("value4", "777");
    sampleObjectMap.put("value5", "444"+i);
    sampleObjectMap.put("value6", "444"+i);
    sampleArrayList.add(sampleObjectMap);
    }

    sampleListAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapterNew(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.cartitem, sampleArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(sampleListAdapter);
}

public class MySimpleArrayAdapterNew extends
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sampleArrayLists;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapterNew(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sampleArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.cartitem, sampleArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.sampleArrayLists = sampleArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.slno = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.slno);
            holder.itemname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
            holder.qty = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            holder.rate = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.rate);
            holder.seatno = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.seat);
            holder.value = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.value);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (WeatherHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final HashMap<String, String> sampleObjectMap = sampleArrayLists
                .get(position);
        holder.itemname.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value1"));
        holder.slno.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value2"));
        holder.qty.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value3"));
        holder.rate.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value4"));
        holder.seatno.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value5"));
        holder.value.setText(sampleObjectMap.get("value6"));
        holder.rate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                String currentrate = sampleObjectMap.get("value4");
                try {
                    if (!((sampleObjectMap.get("value4")) == null)) {
                        sampleObjectMap.put("value4", Caption.getText()
                                .toString());
                        int currentquantity = Integer
                                .parseInt(sampleObjectMap.get("value3"));
                        sampleObjectMap.put(
                                "value6",
                                (Double.parseDouble(sampleObjectMap
                                        .get("value4")) * (currentquantity))
                                        + "");
                        sampleArrayList.set(position, sampleObjectMap);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                    ne.printStackTrace();

                    sampleObjectMap.put("value4", currentrate);
                    sampleArrayList.add(sampleObjectMap);

                }

                if (!hasFocus) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (hasFocus) {

                }
            }
        });

        holder.qty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                try {
                    if (!((sampleObjectMap.get("value3")) == null)) {
                        sampleObjectMap.put("value3", Caption.getText()
                                .toString());
                        int currentquantity = Integer
                                .parseInt(sampleObjectMap.get("value3"));
                        sampleObjectMap.put(
                                "value6",
                                (Double.parseDouble(sampleObjectMap
                                        .get("value4")) * (currentquantity))
                                        + "");
                        sampleArrayList.set(position, sampleObjectMap);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                    ne.printStackTrace();
                    sampleObjectMap.put("value3", "1");
                    sampleArrayList.add(sampleObjectMap);
                }
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (hasFocus) {

                }
            }
        });
        holder.seatno.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                sampleObjectMap.put("value5", Caption.getText().toString());
                sampleArrayList.set(position, sampleObjectMap);
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (hasFocus) {

                }
            }
        });
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

    public class WeatherHolder {
        TextView slno;
        TextView itemname;
        EditText qty;
        EditText rate;
        EditText seatno;
        TextView value;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: i know this code is a mess. please try to go through it.

Comment: To get the focus working for the list cell. A useful link

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13711066/1352919

Answer (score 0):

This changes may help.

First, change to listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    />
```

Then, add this in your Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name= ".yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```