# EditText losing focus in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus, lostfocus

I already read tons of similar questions, but I found no solution that fixed my problem, so please do not mark this as duplicate.

I have a `ListFragment` with a `FrameLayout` containing a `ListView`, populated through a `custom ArrayListAdapter`.
Each row of the list has three elements:

`Checkbox`, `EditText` and `ImageButton`.

My problem is that when I tap on an `EditText` to change the `string` it contains the keyboard shows up, but the focus immediately goes away and I'm not able to write.

Please note that I already have added to my `Activity` in the `manifest` file

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

even the

> android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
>   android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

doesn't solve the problem.

Here is my XML code:

row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_checkbox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="60px"
    android:text="Test text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_checkbox"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_important"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_important" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_important"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    >

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

</FrameLayout>
```

It would be great if you could suggest me some resource where to understand how focusability works in this case.

Thank you

---

UPDATE

I found out the problem is created by the keyboard showing up: I guess the view recycling is the reason why the `EditText` loses focus.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview

Comment: I already tried that solution, unfortunately is not solving the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue using the new `RecyclerView` class. It seems that was a problem of the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/item_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:focusable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_important"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_checkbox"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/item_important"
    android:minHeight="60px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_important"
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="20dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
>

 <ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Activity Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);

    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    /**mArrayList.add("Test");
    mArrayList.add("Test");
    mArrayList.add("Test");
    mArrayList.add("Test");**/

    CustomeAdapter adapter = new CustomeAdapter(this, mArrayList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> mArrayList;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> users) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, users);
        mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mArrayList = users;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);
            viewHolder.mEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            viewHolder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_important);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.mEditText.setText(mArrayList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    // View lookup cache
    private class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox mCheckBox;
        EditText mEditText;
        ImageView mImageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tryed your code on my mobile device with Android API 16 and it still has the same problem. Then I tested it on a virtual device with Android API 21 and it works. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on your `EditText`?

Also the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your AndroiManifest file.